# Вопрос по for и break

Tags: php, циклы, php5

Если писать так:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=0; $i++){
    echo $i."<br>";
        break;
}
echo $i;
```

то ответ:

```
0
0
```

А если так:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=0; $i++){
    echo $i."<br>";
}
echo $i;
```

то ответ:

```
0
1
```

Почему так происходит, разве после прерывании с помощью `break` не должен выполняться дальше `$i++`?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php
break прерывает выполнение - читай выходит из конструкции цикла в тот момент, когда на него натыкается. При этом цикл for выполняет приращение, только перед вторым проходом цикла. Соответственно он не срабатывает после оператора break.

Comment: Вообще break без условий типа if(что-то там){break;} в цикле for не имеет смысла. Так какпроще обойтись совсем без цикла. Это будет одно и то же.

Answer (score 0):

Само значение английского слова `break` - прервать, то есть выйти из цикла немедленно.

Противоположное значение имеет ключевое слово `continue` которое также прерывает выполнение текущей итерации цикла, но возвращает управление управляющему предложению цикла в ту его часть, где выполняется выражение `$i++` , и цикл продолжится, если условие цикла по-прежнему будет истинно.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на структуру оператора **for**:

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)  
{
    body  
}
```

Оператор *break* **сразу** завершает ближайший внешний цикл или оператор switch, в котором он появляется. Управление передается оператору, следующему за завершенным оператором (если таковой имеется). В данном примере выходит за пределы цикла, т.е. инкремент переменной не происходит.

Во втором случае нету оператора *break*, т.е. тело цикла выполняется пока верно выражение **condition**.

Для того чтобы чтобы прервать выполнение текущей итерации цикла и перейти к следующей используется оператор **continue**

**Важно!** Сначала выполняется **iterator**, а уже после него вычисляется **condition**. **Iterator** выполняется только один раз - в самом начале работы цикла, перед всеми частями цикла. В этом случае **iterator** пропускается и выполняется проверка условия **condition**